# EasyMock throwing incompatible return value type on final method

Tags: java, junit, easymock

Basically, I'm trying to set the result of a final method. The method is simple, like this:

```
@NotNull
public final Server getServer() {
    return this.server;
}
```

I mock it like this:

```
EasyMock.expect(object.getServer()).andReturn(server);
```

Where server is a POJO. This throws this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: incompatible return value type
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.andReturn(MocksControl.java:281)
```

For that line.
I tried not using a POJO for server, and mocking it instead.

```
@Mock
private Server server = mock(Server.class);
```

Yet still the same error. I'm absolutely positive that they are the exact same type. Why is this happening?

Now, for some reason I get a different error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
```

Same code, all I have is this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    EasyMock.expect(object.getServer()).andReturn(server);
    replayAll();
    TestedObject.useObject(object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get an error when mocking a final method is that it is not supported by EasyMock. https://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking-limitations

> Final methods cannot be mocked. If called, their normal code will be executed.

You can use PowerMock to mock final and static methods.